# JS OOP Built In Object Array

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var v = new Array('Bill','Erik','Pam');
v.toString();
v.constructor;
```

In Firebug 1.7.3, FF 5.0.1

```
v.constructor //Returns "undefined, not Array();
```

also:

```
 var s = new String('Couch Potato');


    s.indexOf('Couch');
    s.slice(1,5);
    s.split(" ");
    s.join(' ');  //FF returns "s.join" is not a function.
```

Why is this?

Comment: `join` is an array function in JavaScript. Btw, `v.constructor` shows `function Array() {[native code]}` in the web console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the constructor property, apparently firebug has a bug. try alerting that value (`alert([].constructor)`) and you'll see that it is not `undefined`.
The `join` method is an array method and it's normal for firebug to show an error when calling it on a string. In javascript, the `String` is not an array of `char` like in other languages (probably you got confused).
The only way you can call the `join` method in your case would be after you transformed your string into an array : `"abcd".split('').join('')`.

Comment: Your explanation follows the publication example. My experiment led me astray.

Answer (score 2):

In FF 5.0.1, I get this result:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

typeof arr.constructor // function
```

But without the `typeof`, I get this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

arr.constructor // [ undefined ]
```

...which does show `undefined`, but it is in an Array. I'm guessing this is simply a display issue in FireBug.

Try doing this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

var arr_2 = arr.constructor( 4,5,6 );
```

...you'll see that `arr_2` is the Array you'd expect.

With regard to your `.join()` not being a function, it is because `s` is still a String, not an Array. This is because `.split()` does not change the String into an Array, but rather *returns* an Array.

You could do this,

```
s = s.split(" ");
var joined = s.join(' ');
```

... and it will work.

Comment: In the Web Console, it shows `function Array() {[native code]}`.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, looks like a FireBug display issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as for the constructor (it works OK on Chrome), but the `join` method is not of strings, neither of Strings.

You can join an array into a string, e.g.

```
[1, 2, 3].join(" ") === "1 2 3";
```

But the string cannot be joined - what should it do?